# Sum of identity and idempotent (projection) matrix

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

Let $P$ be an idempotent $n \times n$ matrix ($P^2 = P$). What is $(I + P)^{-1}$? I've been thinking about this problem for a while, but can't find an answer. I tried a few examples, but I'm not sure what the general pattern is.

Comment: What is the scalar field?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If $0 \neq 2$ in the field and $P^2=P$, then the minimal Polynomial of $P$ divides $f := x^2-x$, which means it is $f$, $x$, or $x-1$. If it is $x$, $P=0$, and if it is $x-1$, $P=1$. Those cases are clear.

So suppose it is $x^2-x$. Then $I+P$ has minimal polynomial $(x-1)(x-2)=x^2-3x+2$. This means that $I$ is $((I+P)^2-3(I+P))/(-2)$ and so
$(I+P)^{-1}$ is $(I+P-3I)/(-2)=(P-2I)/(-2)$

Answer (score 2):

Hint:
$$
(I+P)(P-2I)=P-2I+P-2P=-2I
$$